# How to create a SaveAndContinue button on UI Component form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, forms, custom-button

I'm new at magento 2 and I'm trying to create a "SaveAndContinue" button.

I created the classes, but when i click the SaveAndContinue button on the form, it calls the "save" controller and not the "save and continue" controller. What could it be?

form.xml

```
            <button name="save_and_continue" class="Hub\Api\Block\Adminhtml\Data\Edit\Buttons\SaveAndContinue" />
```

SaveAndContinue button:

```
class SaveAndContinue extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
```

{

```
/**
 * Get buttong attributes
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getButtonData()
{
    return [
        'label' => __('Save and Continue Edit'),
        'class' => 'save',
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => [
                'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndContinueEdit'],
            ],
        ],
        'sort_order' => 80,
    ];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the default behavior of magento clicking the **Save and Continue Edit** Button will take you to the **"Save"** Controller only.

However in the Save Controller you will get a URL Param called ***"back"***. If this parameter is present in the URL the control will be redirected to the Edit Page.

If the ***"back"*** parameter is not present it will redirect to the index page.(i.e Grid Page). The URL parameter will look like this below

```
save/key/50ae7415daa8cc17732a255e3da805d43e2dba60d74fcd54b1ba6e73ea2d30b3/back/edit
```

Comment: So i did a getUrl(), and it returns this:  localhost/loja/admin/api/index/index/key/face431fead2129e4bf0079cbdce6f2022eb8828c0d76fe476e79b02e4e91f94/

Comment: And this is the return i use on the Save Controller: return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');

Comment: So if the SaveAndContinue Button calls Save Controller, how the controller could knows wich one got clicked?

Comment: Can you try this piece  of code  $this->getRequest()->getParam('back') in your save controller. if it returns true redirect to edit page

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1:** Create Generic.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;

class Generic
{
    protected $context;
    protected $pageRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository
    ) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function getUrl($route = '', $params = [])
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

**Step-2:** Create Back.php at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Button

```
    <?php

    namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

    class ApplyButton extends Generic implements ButtonProviderInterface
    {
        public function getButtonData()
        {
            return [
                'label' => __('Save and Continue'),
                'class' => 'save',
                'on_click' => '',
                'sort_order' => 50,
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => [
                        'Magento_Ui/js/form/button-adapter' => [
                            'actions' => [
                                [
                                    'targetName' => 'your_form_ui_component_name.your_form_ui_component_name',
                                    'actionName' => 'save',
                                    'params' => [
                                        true,
                                        [
                                            'save_and_continue' => 1,
                                        ],
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],

                ],
            ];
        }
    }
```

**Step-3:** In your Form Ui-Component file at app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component add below code:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        ............................................................................................................
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            ............................................................................................................
            <item name="apply" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Button\ApplyButton</item>
            ............................................................................................................
        </item>
        ............................................................................................................
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="your_form_data_source_name">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">your_form_data_source_name</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
              </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    ................................................................................................................
</form>
```

After adding above files run below command:

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
```